# Laravel 5.2: Things are being changed after multiple page reload?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching

This is something strange happening from last couple weeks in my project.

Whenever I make any changes in controller, balde or any file, changes take effect after multiple random page refresh.

Even I have tried with artisan commands:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear


// Cache & Session setting in .env file
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

I am facing this issue first time, I don't why it's behaving like this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it happening in local or production environment ? If it's happening on your production environment and you don't have full control on how the server cache your files, you may try to add a random parameter to the url to force it to reset the cache. And you could do the same for your assets. Something like `https://url.com?reset=64651`

Comment: it's on my local environment

Comment: Alright, then you probably have OPcache enabled in your php.ini. Try to disable it and restart Apache. Did you upgrade or reinstall your environement recently ? That would explain why it showed up suddenly.

Comment: Seems that things are working fine after disabling the OPcache, Thanks Buddy..Previously project was setup on different laptop, recently configured on new one.

Comment: Glad it helped :)